# Selenium IwebDriver pasing thru a method

Tags: selenium, c#

Below is my code ,
and it works fine

```
 public static void WaitTillthisclassName(string elemantName, int TimefromMSeconds)
        {
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(TimefromMSeconds));
            wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.ClassName(elemantName)));

        }
```

But at there im passing `elemantName` as `string` 
I need to pass a `IWebElement` type `elemantName`.

how am i going to do this?

And i also tried passing IWebElemant ,but got bellow errors.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public static void WaitTillthisclassName(IWebElement element, int TimefromMSeconds)
        {
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(TimefromMSeconds));
            wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists((OpenQA.Selenium‌​.By)element));

        }
```

Comment: ooh, i did the same ;But some error came to the action,.

Comment: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement' to 'OpenQA.Selenium.By'

Comment: seems like ElementExists does not accept IWebElement as param

Comment: this has no compilation errors, try to see if it works:
 wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists((OpenQA.Selenium.By)element));

Comment: Yahya H Hussein  it works. Please add as a Answer

Comment: Good! Answer updated

Comment: ooh boy. Another exception at the run time from the above code.{"Unable to cast transparent proxy to type 'OpenQA.Selenium.By'."}

Comment: This is a very good question. In page objects you get proxy elements created during PageObject initialization. The only way to determine that this element is actually present or not is by making a call to do some task.

For eg do a webelement.getText() and catch exceptions. If you get NoSuchElementException that means element is not present.

your code will look like this

public static boolean isElementPresent(WebElement element) {
try {
   element.getText();
   return true;
} catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
return false;
}

Comment: http://forumsqa.com/question/how-to-check-if-an-page-object-web-element-exists/

Comment: Let me try this .

Comment: It actually is a stupid solution, I am seriously thinking to stop using PageFactory as it has many annoying things, one of them is you will not be able to change FindsBy parameter, and this is another